# Compiling apps with Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am using Visual Studio IDE with react native and nodejs for creating native mobile apps, my code is compiled to platform native code.
I'm asking of what part of this tool compiles my code in os-native source?

Comment: The documentation is a good place to start. https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/workflow/how-expo-works/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How Expo Works**

Forget about Expo for a second and let’s just discuss React Native.

A React Native app is a compiled app that is running some Javascript. Whenever you build and run your React Native project, a packager starts up called `Metro`.

The packager does a few things:

1.Combines all your Javascript code into a single file, and translates any Javascript code that your device won’t understand (like JSX or some of the newer JS syntax) to native code.

2.Converts assets (e.g. PNG files) into objects that can be displayed by an Image component.

When you aren’t using Expo, you run your app like this.

```
react-native start
```

With Expo though, you run it like this (using their CLI tool).

```
exp start
```

Both of these commands start up the same packager that we just discussed. The difference is that exp start also starts something called the Expo Development Server. This server runs a process that grabs your Javascript bundle created by the React Native packager (Metro), and runs it inside the Expo app on your simulator.

Read detailed article [here  by **Mark Newton**](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-expo-for-react-native-7bf23054bbcd)

Also refer official documentation on [how-expo-works](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/how-expo-works/)